# How do I remove the noise while improving the contrast of a real time video?

Tags: python, real-time, noise, noise-reduction, high-contrast

I have been working on this code which is a video captured by an IR camera. I need to improve the contrast while omitting the noise and this shadow cast that occurs. I have simply applied CLAHE and Histogram Equalization with medianBlur in python but I want to improve these results.

[image]

Here is the code

```
ret, frame = cap.read() 
    i = cv2.flip(frame,1)        
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(i, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    m=cv2.medianBlur(gray,3)
    equ = cv2.equalizeHist(m)
    m1=cv2.medianBlur(equ,3)
    clahe1 = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=1.0, tileGridSize=(10,10))
    cl1 = clahe1.apply(m1)
    cl2=clahe1.apply(cl1)
    m=cv2.medianBlur(cl2,3)
    cl3=clahe1.apply(m)
    cl3 = cv2.medianBlur(cl3,3)
```